# How to copy HTML as plain text

Tags: html, summernote

When I copy paste some text from somewhere to a summernote text editor, it copies the style also. What I need is just the plain text. But what I'm getting is the text with a number of html tags.

When I copy

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry
```

What I'm getting is

```
<strong style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum</strong><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14px; text-align: justify;">&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span>
```

The code I'm using is

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    focus : true,
    height: 250,
    toolbar: []
});
```

Is there any option in summernote to disable this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste content as plain text in summernote editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993836/paste-content-as-plain-text-in-summernote-editor)

Answer (score 3):

Summernote has an onPaste event, which can be implemented like so:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    focus : true,
    height: 250,
    toolbar: [],
    onPaste: function(e) {

    })
});
```

You can see an implementation of how someone used this to strip formatting here: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/303#issuecomment-53713694

Comment: I tried this. But for me the onpaste event never triggers

Comment: Have you tried just doing a simple alert inside of that? It doesn't fire at all?

Comment: yeah a simple console.log('hi'). and it dosen't fire

Comment: Could it be the difference between onpaste and onPaste? Example has it as onpaste, but if you change it to onPaste it should work

Comment: Yep same for me... Does not trigger at all. But then again, almost nothing from the settings work except the toolbar :/

Answer (score 0):

For disable onPaste event

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
  onPaste: function(e) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  } 
});
```